# How to compare string with for loop in c#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a mini code generator in c#.  Say i have a string

string val= "i=0;i<5;i++";

As I'm taking complete structure of for loop as a string. How to find the syntax error if user gives wrong input? For example terminator missing or other logical errors? Should i have to use regex?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] showing us your work so far.

Comment: Generator or Parser? It's not clear.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about a parser rather than a generator, which is a much larger set of problems.
For example, instead of entering your simple-case `for` loop, they could enter `i = a + b * 3, j = 7; i < 5 || b % 16 == 4 && (a == 1) ? b == 2 : b == 3; i++, j = Math.Pow(1.1D, a++)` which is perfectly valid, but would be very difficult to first parse with regexes, and then semantically check.

Answer (score 2):

No i don't think regex is good option because you have to take many things into consideration.

but i would suggest try this instead

```
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/304655/how-to-programmatically-compile-code-using-c-compiler
```

using c# compiler itself to do work for you.

but keep that in mind this will ask for whole c# code so you may have to do some string manipulation to get around that.